# Setting access control for different contexts in LDAP through JNDI

Tags: ldap, jndi

I am creating separate contexts (eg: ou=marketing, ou=finance) in LDAP to store user entries of different departments under different contexts.

I need to set the access control at the creation of each context, such that I can give out the url for each context to an admin user of a particular department and he is capable of connecting to the relevant context using any other application or a LDAP browser and view only the user entries under that particular context, but not the other contexts.

Is the above possible to do? After searching on this, I found that in ApacheDS, it is possible to set access control at partition level, but did not find how to set it in context level.

Further, I have the requirement that my application should be able to connected to any LDAP server (like openLDAP, ApacheDS etc..) that user specifies and perform above operations. So I though of using JNDI for that. Is it possible to achieve what I have mentioned above using JNDI programetically?

I would highly appreciate any help on this. Even a reference would be sufficient.

Thanks in advance.
Hasini.

Comment: if its openldap you have to edit your slapd.conf for acccess control. If its eDirectory or ActiveDirectory you will have fine grained control.

Comment: Most modern directory servers support the concept of access controls, Some adhere to the published standards, others do not. A possible architecture for using the same access controls for each directory server vendor is to front them all with an LDAP proxy server and use the access controls available in the proxy server. Using this method, your configuration tasks will be easier. That being said, the application must not concern itself with LDAP access controls, the application merely takes appropriate action upon receipt of the result code that is part of the LDAP response.